# Switch title text with javascript? HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I've been trying to get the title text to switch between different texts for a day now. I've gathered some code snippets and put them together, so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

function switchingText(); {
  document.getElementByID("title").innerHTML = "Text";
  sleep(2000);
  document.getElementByID("title").innerHTML = "Text2";
  sleep(2000);
  switchingText();
}
```

I would appreciate any help greatly.

Comment: Switch between `Text` and `Text2` every two seconds? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I've just put those there as placeholders. The goal is to have my contact information flash alternatingly.  @dork

Comment: Try looking at [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: Are you trying to get HTML <title> text?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample solution for your dilemma:

```js
const title= document.getElementById("title");

const switchHeading = () => {
    if (title.innerHTML== "Text"){
        title.innerHTML = "Text2";
    }else{
        title.innerHTML = "Text";
    }
} 


setInterval(() => {
    switchHeading()
}, 2000);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1 id="title">Text</h1>
        <script src="./script.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html></html>
```

Helpful links:

[W3Schools Set Interval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: using `document.title` is easier :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get the title element like you did but instead of changing the InnerHTML, change the value, like so:

```
document.getElementByID('title').value="Text"
```

Hope you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
document.getElementByID("title").innerHTML = "Text";
```

in the switching text function,
you need to do

```
document.title = 'your text'
```